# Python: Reread contents of a file

Tags: python, file, io, refresh

I have a file that an application updates every few seconds, and I want to extract a single number field in that file, and record it into a list for use later. So, I'd like to make an infinite loop where the script reads a source file, and any time it notices a change in a particular figure, it writes that figure to an output file.

I'm not sure why I can't get Python to notice that the source file is changing:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re
from time import gmtime, strftime, sleep



def write_data(new_datapoint):
        output_path = '/media/USBHDD/PythonStudy/torrent_data_collection/data_one.csv'
        outfile = open(output_path, 'a')
        outfile.write(new_datapoint)
        outfile.close()


forever = 0
previous_data = "0"

while forever < 1:
        input_path = '/var/lib/transmission-daemon/info/stats.json'
        infile = open(input_path, "r")
        infile.seek(0)
        contents = infile.read()

        uploaded_bytes = re.search('"uploaded-bytes":\s(\d+)', contents)

        if uploaded_bytes:
                current_time = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %X", gmtime())
                current_data = uploaded_bytes.group(1)
                if current_data != previous_data:
                        write_data(","+ current_time + "$" + uploaded_bytes.group(1))
                        previous_data = uploaded_bytes.group(1)
                infile.close()
                sleep(5)
        else:
                print "couldn't write" + strftime("%Y-%m-%d %X", gmtime())
                infile.close()
                sleep(60)
```

As is now, the (messy) script writes once correctly, and then I can see that although my source file (stats.json) file is changing, my script never picks up on any changes. It keeps on running, but my output file doesn't grow.

I thought that an `open()` and a `close()` would do the trick, and then tried throwing in a `.seek(0)`.

What file method am I missing to ensure that python re-opens and re-reads my source file, (stats.json)?

Comment: Is the "other application" beyond your control or do you have the opportunity to modify its code?

Comment: yes, it is beyond my control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers, unfortunately my error was in the shell, and not in the script with Python.

The cause of the problem turned out to be the way I was putting the script in the background. I was doing: `Ctrl+Z` which I thought would put the task in the background. But it does not, `Ctrl+Z` only suspends the task and returns you to the shell, a subsequent `bg` command is necessary for the script to run on infinite loop in the background

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are implementing some synchronization mechanism or could guarantee somehow atomic read and write, I think you are calling for race condition and subtle bugs here.

Imagine the "reader" accessing the file whereas the "writer"  hasn't completed its write cycle. There is a risk of reading incomplete/inconsistent data. In "modern" systems, you could also hit the cache -- and not seeing file modifications "live" as they appends.

Comment: but how come this script only works the first time? I am reading the file more often than the file is being changed by the other application.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two possible solutions:

1. You forgot the parentheses on the close in the else of the infinite loop.
   `infile.close` --> `infile.close()`
2. The program that is changing the JSON file is not closing the file, and therefore it is not actually changing.

Comment: 1. fixed the parentheses, it was a mispaste          2. in my shell, I can `cat` the contents of the file and see it changes every few seconds

Answer (score 1):

**Two problems I see:**

1. Are you sure your file is really updated on filesystem? I do not know on what operating system you are playing with your code, but caching may kick your a$$ in this case, if the files is not flushed by *producer*.
2. Your problem is worth considering *pipe* instead of file, however I cannot guarantee what `transmission` will do if it stuck on writing to pipe if your *consumer* is dead.

Answering your problems, consider using one of the following:

- [pynotifyu](http://pyinotify.sourceforge.net/)
- [watchdog](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog/0.5.4)
- [watcher](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/watcher)

These modules are intended to monitor changes on filesystem and then call proper actions. Method in your example is primitive, has big performance penalty and couple other problems mentioned already in other answers.

Comment: performance isn't an issue, running on a Raspberry pi, `htop` says this tasks uses 0.0% CPU and 1% Memory. This script is also one of the few things that I want to run on the machine.   I'll check out those workarounds, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ilya, would it help to check(**os.path.getmtime**), whether *stats.json* changed before you process the file?

Moreover, i'd suggest to make advantage of the fact it's JSON file:

```
import json
import os
import sys

dir_name ='/home/klaus/.config/transmission/' 
# stats.json of daemon might be elsewhere

file_name ='stats.json'
full_path = os.path.join(dir_name, file_name)

with open(full_path) as fp:
    json.load(fp)
    data = json.load(fp)
    print data['uploaded-bytes']
```